# Column repetition when creating a oracle view

Tags: oracle, view

I have created a view as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW classsession AS 
   SELECT 
      c.classid, min(s.startTime) as firstsession
   FROM 
      class c, session s, classSession cs
   WHERE 
      c.classid = cs.classid and cs.sessionid = s.sessionid
   GROUP BY 
      c.classid
```

When I am running this query the contents of the view is repeating

Could any one can give me solution.

Comment: What is your output and what do you expect?

Comment: Could be great if you use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to build self-containing code example

Comment: The output is correctly showing but it is repeating

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style should **no longer be used** and instead it is recommended to use the **proper ANSI JOIN** syntax introduced with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: I've been using ANSI-89 for 5 years in Oracle and I haven't had any problems with it.

Comment: The query is running correctly.But when creating the view using the query results is repeating 581 times.Should I change any settings? @ Arion

Comment: On the face of it, what you say is happening cannot be - the GROUP BY query can only return 1 row per c.classid value. That's why we need to see the output you are actually getting (and the real query if the one above isn't it already).  Also, show us the query you run to select from the view.